# pip: Ignore dependencies of dependencies on --force-reinstall

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I wonder is there any way of ignoring dependencies of dependencies?

Basically I have build a package in python and have added some dependencies and those dependencies have further dependencies.

Is there a way to skip reinstalling of a specific dependencies?

Here is the cmd i am running.

`pip install my-private-package-name --force-reinstall --upgrade`

Let's suppose my package have dependency `pandas` and that dependency have further dependency `xyz` I want to skip `xyz`

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The `--no-deps` flag will skip installing dependencies.

Comment: I want to skip specific dependency please check updated description :)

Comment: Then no, there's no option I know of to skip installing a specific dependency. You can work around that by installing once with `--no-deps`, and then manually install the dependencies you do want.